# d3.js setrequestheader fails in ie8

Tags: d3.js

Can someone say how to set a request header using the d3js xhr interface in IE8?

Code is like this:

```
d3.csv(url).header("accept","text/csv").rows(function(d) {...}).get(function(e,r) {...});
```

This doesn't have the desired effect in IE8, but works in Firefox and Chrome.

I load the aight compatibility library before loading d3, and the aight.d3 library after, but I don't think those are relevant to this problem.

The request is sent, but the response type is incorrect (it's json instead of csv), so the rows() function fails to get any data. At the server, the "Accept:" header value is `*/*` from IE8, but `text/csv` from other browsers.

When I write the equivalent in bare javascript, IE8 sets the request header correctly.

I have d3 version 3.4.3.

Thanks for any help.

Regards,
--Paul

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm not an expert on the subject, but looking through [the d3 source code](https://github.com/mbostock/d3/blob/f59fc64a20d57fe08be9fb6e53ab0022f6f6c732/src/xhr/xhr.js) and various MSDN references, I think the problem is that d3 automatically checks whether you're using an absolute url reference, and if so assumes that it is a cross-domain request and switches to IE's XDomainRequest instead of XMLHttpRequest for older IE.

Relevant d3 source code ([line 17-26](https://github.com/mbostock/d3/blob/f59fc64a20d57fe08be9fb6e53ab0022f6f6c732/src/xhr/xhr.js)):

```
var xhr = {},
      dispatch = d3.dispatch("beforesend", "progress", "load", "error"),
      headers = {},
      request = new XMLHttpRequest,
      responseType = null;

  // If IE does not support CORS, use XDomainRequest.
  if (d3_window.XDomainRequest
      && !("withCredentials" in request)
      && /^(http(s)?:)?\/\//.test(url)) request = new XDomainRequest;
```

The first line tests whether the `XDomainRequest` object exists ([it does for IE8 and up](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ie/cc288060%28v=vs.85%29.aspx)), the second tests if the created `XMLHttpRequest` object does not have the `withCredentials` property for cross-domain requests ([which only exists in IE10 and up](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ie/hh872883%28v=vs.85%29.aspx)), and the third tests whether the url starts with "http://" or "https://".

So, if you pass in an absolute url to any of the d3 file-grabbing functions in an IE8 or IE9 browser, it will use an `XDomainRequest` object instead of `XMLHttpRequest`.

Which is good if you want to actually grab files from a cross-origin server.  Not so good if your same-domain server is expecting you to specify the accepted file type, since as far as I can tell [`XDomainRequest` doesn't have any way of setting headers](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ie/cc288060%28v=vs.85%29.aspx), and it certainly doesn't have the `setRequestHeader` method that d3 checks for ([line 96](https://github.com/mbostock/d3/blob/f59fc64a20d57fe08be9fb6e53ab0022f6f6c732/src/xhr/xhr.js)):

```
  xhr.send = function(method, data, callback) {
    /*...*/
    if (request.setRequestHeader) for (var name in headers) 
           request.setRequestHeader(name, headers[name]);
    /*...*/
```

So how do you get it to work?  If you're not doing a cross-origin request (and therefore `XMLHttpRequest` should work fine), specify your URL using relative notation if you can.  Otherwise, you're either going to have to change the d3 source code or create the XMLHttpRequest yourself.